# Using iDangerous Swiper - Movie App

Tags: jquery

I love the iDangerous swipers I have used the main one and vertical swiper in other projects and they worked fine.  In this instance I am trying to use the movie app version and I can't seem to get it to work.  I am using the script at the bottom of my html and my html matches that of the demos, here is the script I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
var swiperMovies = $('.mc-posters').swiper({
    mode : "horizontal", 
    onlyExternal : true,
    speed:1000
});
var allowMovieClick = true
var swiperMControl = $('.mc-control').swiper({
    mode : "horizontal", 
    scrollContainer:true,
    onTouchMove : function(){
        allowMovieClick = true  
    },
    onTouchEnd : function() {
        setTimeout(function(){allowMovieClick = true},100)  
    }
});
$('.mc-control img').bind('mousedown',function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
})
$('.mc-control img').bind('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    if (!allowMovieClick) return;
    var index = $(this).index()
    swiperMovies.swipeTo ( index )
    $('.mc-control .active').removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass('active')
});
})
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: What isn't working about it?

Comment: You should be able to click on a thumbnail and the image slides to that corresponding information but at this point the thumbnail is not even clickable.